# Created an insert forum using HTML/PHP but I get error when adding a certain amount of content

Tags: php, html, mysql

I've very new to this, and it's part of a University project which I decided to go the extra mile in.

I've created a HTML form to insert rows into a table on a MYSQL database.  The form works fine when limited number of characters are entered but when I try over a certain amount I get an error.  I'm using VARCHAR's for all columns and their limits are far higher than the text I am trying to insert.

Here is my code

```
<html>
 <body>
   <h1>Add new entries to Home and News page here</h1>

    <form action="insert.php" method="post">
        <br>Date: <input type="date" name="date"></br>
        <br>Title: <input type="text" name="title"></br>
        <br>Body:<input type="text" name="body" </br>
        <br>Media: <input type="text" name="media"></br>
        <br>ID: <input type="text" name="id"</br>
        <input type="submit">
   </form>

 </body>
</html>
```

and the PHP

```
<?php
   $con=mysqli_connect("***","****","****","*****");  
    // Check connection
   if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
   }

   $sql = "INSERT INTO news (date, title, body, media, id)
           VALUES
           ('$_POST[date]','$_POST[title]','$_POST[body]','$_POST[media]','$_POST[id]')";

   if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
        die('Error ' . mysqli_error());
   }

    echo "1 record added";

   mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

A point in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you give us the error message ?

Comment: Be careful about sql injection ...

Comment: Hi there.  The error message is just from my code 'die('Error ' . mysqli_error());' There is no specific message, it's just not inserted into the table.  Also, it seems to be a case of how much i'm trying to insert on the entire page, as opposed to each individual field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the error you're receiving?  Please note your error trapping may be incorrect, try:

```
die ('Error: '.mysqli_error ($con));
```

I notice you're not escaping (making safe) the data being sent by the user.  So if for example I set my "title" to:

```
This is my title, '; SQL INJECTION; '
```

I'd break your code:

```
INSERT INTO news (date, title, body, media, id)
VALUES
('date','This is my title, '; SQL INJECTION; '','body','media','id')";
```

You can resolve this by using any method of "escaping" (making safe) the values you're putting into your query.  There's literally a hundred ways you could do this, if you've been asked to the mysqi_*() functions, you could do it thusly:

```
$date = mysqli_real_escape_string ($con, $_POST['date']);
$title = mysqli_real_escape_string ($con, $_POST['title']);
$body = mysqli_real_escape_string ($con, $_POST['body']);
$media = mysqli_real_escape_string ($con, $_POST['media']);
$id = mysqli_real_escape_string ($con, $_POST['id']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO news (date, title, body, media, id)
       VALUES
       ('$date','$title','$body','$media','$id')";
```

**So an explanation of what's happening:**
([XKCD has a nice joke about the subject.](http://xkcd.com/327/))

Without the mysqli_real_escape_string, you're building the SQL query ($sql) with anything the user is posting through the form.  That's all fine and dandy, providing they don't end up altering your SQL statement.

So if they insert a single quote: ', the SQL will end up invalid, because the "VALUES ('$title')" for example could become "VALUES ('An adventure's dream')", notice how MySQL is going to see 'An adventure' as the value, and "s dream'" as some broken stuff on the end?

With the inclusion of "mysqli_real_escape_string()", any bad symbols (like a single quote) are *escaped*, which for MySQL means having a "\" added in front of it.  That tells MySQL to ignore the symbol - and treat it as data, rather than an SQL command.

For easy debugging - I'd suggest putting:

```
 print "<pre>$sql</pre>";
```

just after you create $sql.  That way you can see exactly what's being sent to MySQL.

(Personally I prefer using PHP's PDO library - which if you're interested in the subject, is worth a read.  It has some cool features for escaping stuff :))

Really hope you enjoy studying your degree!

FYI:
The VARCHAR(255) should silently chop your data to 255 characters long, without raising an error.

Comment: Hi Wally, thanks for the reply.  

In regards to the error message, it's just it's coming from die('Error ' . mysqli_error()); } so I can't really be more specific. 

I was going to looking into the security of it if I had chance, but I wanted to get it functioning first.

Comment: I added the con to the trapping like you said and I get this error message:

Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's just it's coming from die('Error ' . mysqli_error()); } **whatever text was added**

Comment: It's security as you're putting it then.  I'll update my answer, check it in a few minutes!

Comment: Very insightful Wally, i'm really enjoying this and definitely looking at learning more.  Thanks for the help and advice.

Comment: Your error is linked to the data injected, Filter input data first.

Answer (score 0):

That is because in mysql you fill in for example your body contains varchar(255) which means the body of the news can only contain 255 charachters this also include spaces.

If you want to be able to fill in more characters just make the number varchar(5000) for example bigger